# Share code between areas ASP.net MVC

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

We have a ASP.net MVC application organized using different Areas. We are adding a new functionality that works across areas and we want to reuse some view models for this functionality in the different Areas.

We were thinking in a BaseViewModel and BaseViewModel builder classes in some "shared folder" and then implementing the subclasses in each Area.

Is this a good approach? Are there any guidelines to share code between Areas in ASP.net MVC?

Comment: Yes that's fine, no there is no guidelines. This is basic object orientation. Nothing to do with MVC. MVC is a presentation pattern (not a technology), it is concerned with presenting data to a UI. It has nothing to do with how your organise your business logic, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach sounds reasonable.

In our project, we have the shared ViewModels in `{Project Root}\Models` and the corresponding *.cshtml files in  `{Project Root}\Views\Shared`.

The Area specific ViewModels reside in `{Project Root}\Areas\{Area}\Models` and their Views in `{Project Root}\Areas\{Area}\Views`.

As a side note, I would not introduce a BaseViewModel. Prefer [composition over inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance), this will make maintenance easier. If you need to display common data on different pages, introduce shared ViewModels and Partial Views for these common data, then add the Sub-ViewModels to the ViewModels of the pages and render them with `@Html.PartialFor()`. Here is an example of composition:

```
public class Models.PatientOverviewViewModel {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
}

public class Areas.Patient.Models.PatientDetailsViewModel {
    public PatientOverviewViewModel Overview { get; set; }
    public string MobilePhone { get; set; }
}
```

~\Areas\Patient\Views\PatientDetails.cshtml:

```
@model Areas.Patient.Models.PatientDetailsViewModel
@Html.Partial("_PatientOverview", Model.Overview)
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.MobilePhone)
```

~\Views\Shared_PatientOverview.cshtml:

```
@model Models.PatientOverviewViewModel
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Name)
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.BirthDate)
```

Comment: Seconded to *Prefer composition over inheritance*. Inheritance should always be used with caution for fear of making a rod for your own back later on

Comment: Yes, I also prefer composition, but I miss mixins in C#. Without them the composition is a bit messy. You have two options: expose the inner model or create a lot of "wrapping" code.